# How to keep nulls in a Spring GET servlet?

Tags: java, json, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @GetMapping("/get)
    public void get(Map<String, String> params) {
        println(params.get("optional")); //"null"
    }

    @PostMapping("/post)
    public void post(Map<String, String> params) {
        println(params.get("optional")); //null
    }
}

localhost:8080/get?key=value&optional=null
```

Result: the value of the key `optional` will be `"null"` written as `String`, not as `null` type.

Whereas a `POST` request would work as follows:

```
{
    "key": "value",
    "optional": null
}
```

Question: how can I make the `GET` request behave the same as `POST`? Means, how can I tell spring to interpret the null string in a GET as a real null?

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass `null` via HTTP query parameter like you do it in JSON. Because `null` within an HTTP query has no special meaning and is treated like any other string. 
Instead just don't pass `optional` parameter at all

```
localhost:8080/get?key=value
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this as well.

```
@RequestParam(name = "optional", required = false) String optional
```

[Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html)

Comment: This won't help when "null" string is passed

Comment: Correct but you can drop the optional parm and "String optional" will be NULL for the rest of code to work with

Answer (score 1):

Like @Nikolai says, null has no special meaning in the query. The query is often called the `Query String` such as in AWS API Gateway, which is more descriptive that it tells you that it is a String, it isn't a `Map`, `Strings` only have `chars` encoded, there is no concept of a null in this context.

IMO it isn't good practice to use a `Map<String,String> params` if you can avoid it, rather prefer strong types and list all the possible query params with optional parameters for non-required inputs. If you want the users to specify a `Map` it should be in the BODY, but a `GET` with a body feels wrong to me so you might need to then change the HTTP method.

If you have many parameters, and that's why you are using a `Map`, remember some browsers limit the chars in a URL to `2048`, so it can be dangerous and you may have a case whereby the user cannot specify all the parameters they need to because of this limit.

**TL;DR:** `Map<String,String>` should be in request body.